# How to make a temporary query everytime someone logs in my database?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to make it so every time a student logins to this database it creates a query showing their grades by matching up the FullName in the LoginTable and the FullName in the StudentGrades table by DLookup and QueryDef (Which I have little idea on how to use so I probably got it completely wrong). If you know how to fix this, explain QueryDef, or know an easier way to do this than please help me, thanks.

VBA code for login button:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
'If there is no password or username then shows pop-up
'usertext is username box and passtext is password box
If IsNull(Me.usertext) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter login", vbInformation, "LOGIN REQUIRED"
    Me.usertext.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.passtext) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter password", vbInformation, "PASSWORD REQUIRED"
    Me.passtext.SetFocus
'Sets actual values from table to values started above and checks if username and password actually match up with table
Else
   If (IsNull(DLookup("[UserLogin]", "LoginTable", "[UserLogin] ='" & Me.usertext.Value & "'  and password = '" & Me.passtext.Value & "'"))) Then
    MsgBox "Username/password not valid"
'Checks for what securitylvl is the login and sets up studentqry if user is student
Else
    Dim SecurityLvl As Variant
    Dim StudentName As Variant
    Dim StudentQry As QueryDef
    SecurityLvl = DLookup("SecurityLvl", "LoginTable", "[UserLogin] ='" & Me.usertext.Value & "'")
    StudentName = DLookup("FullName", "LoginTable", "[UserLogin] ='" & Me.usertext.Value & "'")
    If (SecurityLvl = "Admin") Then
    MsgBox "Admin Login successful"
    DoCmd.Close
    DoCmd.OpenForm "AdminForm"
    ElseIf (SecurityLvl = "Professor") Then
        MsgBox "Teacher Login successful"
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "TeacherForm"
            ElseIf (SecurityLvl = "Student") Then
            MsgBox "Student Login successful"
            DoCmd.Close
            Set StudentQry = DBVeryinitialprototype.CreateQueryDef("StudentQuery", "Select * from StudentGrades where `FullName` = StudentName")
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "StudentQuery"
            End If
                End If
                    End If
                        End
End Sub
```

Comment: What doesn't work with above code? And why a temp query? Where do you use it? Just run a general query that filters to student in *LoginTable*.

Comment: I'm getting a 424 object error on the StudentQry. How do I make a permanent query and make it show up in accesses query on the navigation? I just looked up how to make a query using VBA and went off the first thing I saw. I don't even know why I put temporary query, I could've just deleted it on a new login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for temp queries to be created/deleted with each login. Simply create a permanent query that runs on dynamic data. Specifically, join *StudentGrades* to *LoginTable* where the output will be the currently logged in user.

Since your Login process is unclear, possibly you have a status field that identifies which student is in current session (unless you clean out all records in *LoginTable* each time).

```sql
SELECT s.* 
FROM StudentGrades s
INNER JOIN LoginTable l 
  ON l.FullName = s.StudentName
WHERE l.LoginStatus = True
```

And ideally you join on IDs instead of full string values. Login should have a combobox allowing pick of students with a hidden bound field as ID or retrieve the corresponding *StudentID* in typed textbox field. This way the *StudentQuery* would then read:

```sql
SELECT s.* 
FROM StudentGrades s
INNER JOIN LoginTable l 
  ON l.StudentID = s.StudentID
WHERE l.LoginStatus = True
```

How to create a permanent query? This should have been covered in your MS Access 101 course:

1. Under the *Create* tab on ribbon, in Queries section click *Query Design*.
2. Use either the *Design View* to create a query with diagram of tables (selecting tables/joins/fields) or *SQL View* to build queries with SQL.
3. When finished drafting, click Save. Query should then show up in Navigation Pane.

Currently, you are going the coding route of creating queries with querydefs. But again there is no need to do this dynamically, simply create only one query once and data should align accordingly.

Comment: I'm doing this for a school project. I'm sorry if I was so confusing at first. Thanks, I got it now.